# Auto Increment in Session using Javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I Need

- i Need Like when user refesh page i need increment the count of session variable.

js code

```
             <script type="text/javascript">
            var count=0;
            var counter=sessionStorage.setItem("count", 0);
            var counters= sessionStorage.getItem("count");
            console.log(counters);
            var page_count =counters;
            if (page_count == 4)
            {
            dataLayer.push({'event':'mobilePromo-android'});
            }
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            var page_count =counters;
            var height= $(window).height();
            if (page_count == 4 )
            {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://domain.com/mobilepopuptracker?from=android", 

                });

                $('body').html('<div class="row flush aligncenter popbx" style="height:'+height+'px"><img src="http://im.gifbt.com/images/logo-300p");              



            }
            else
            {

            }

               counters=counters+1;
        });
            function redirect()
            {

                  var a=$(location).attr('href');
                   window.location.href=a;
            }

        </script>
```

Problem

- count value is not auto increment as Browser is Refrehed.
- console.log(counters) //0 .
- Any suggestion are most welcome.

After value solution code still not working

```
            var counter = null;
            if(sessionStorage.getItem("count") == null)
            {
            counter=sessionStorage.setItem("count", 0);
            counters = 0;
            }
            else
            {
            counters= parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("count"));

            }

            var page_count =counters;
            if (page_count == 4)
            {
            dataLayer.push({'event':'mobilePromo-android'});
            }
            var page_count =counters;
            console.log(page_count);
            var height= $(window).height();
            if (page_count == 4 )
            {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://times.com/mobilepopuptracker?from=android", 

                });

                $('body').html('<div class="row flush aligncenter popbx" style="height:'+height+'px">');                



            }
            else
            {

            }
              counters++;
             console.log(counters);
            function redirect()
            {

                  var a=$(location).attr('href');
                   window.location.href=a;
            }
```

- issue output is till 1 it"S  not incrmenting. what is wrong.

Output

- if counter is set to 0 then it would auto increment to 1. and so on.
- console.log(counters) //01 it should be auto increment.

Refrence link

```
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to check first for session value is available

```
var counter = null;
if(sessionStorage.getItem("count") == null){
  counter=sessionStorage.setItem("count", 1);
  counters = 1;
}else{
  counters= parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("count")); 
  counters++;
   counter=sessionStorage.setItem("count", counters);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ls = sessionStorage.getItem("session-count");
    if(ls) {
        /*Do whatever here*/
        var count = sessionStorage.getItem("session-count");
        sessionStorage.setItem("session-count", parseInt(count) + 1);           
    } else {
        sessionStorage.setItem("session-count", 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: on console.log(counters) o/p:01 its should be 0+i instead

Comment: This snippet works and increments the value, it does not display 01, but 1.

Comment: issue is that on refreshing page count is not incrementing

Comment: Please post your entire code, because it works for me.