# Updating Global Counter Variable on Submit Button Click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to update a global counter variable in JavaScript when a button of type="submit" is clicked.

My submit button is defined like below:

```
<button
  id="submitClicked"
  type="submit"
  value="Add &amp View Next"
>
```

I am using the following code in JavaScript to update a global variable I've called `orderCounter` that increments each time the "Add & View Next" button is clicked:

```
var orderCounter;

window.onload = function () {
  document
    .getElementById("submitClicked")
    .onclick=incrementCounter;
};

function incrementCounter() {
  if (orderCounter == null) {
    orderCounter = 0;
  } else {
    orderCounter = orderCounter + 1;
  }

  alert(orderCounter);
  return orderCounter;
}
```

The `alert` with this code always displays 0. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Note: I've also tried using jquery .click on the `submitClicked` id in addition to using `onClick` within the HTML form.

I realize this should be simple; not sure where I'm going wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: I tried running it, and it works as expected. alert first time 0, second time 1, and so on. But since you're submitting the form, the actual problem might be that you are reloading the page each time you click the button. Thus, the script will reload, and reset the orderCounter variable each time. Working example here http://jsbin.com/qepecikeqo/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that every time you click on the submit button your page refreshes, so the orderCounter varriable resets itself. one solution is to persistently wait so that its value is not reinitialized each time the page is loaded. One solution is to use kookies: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp.
i hope this will welp you

Comment: thank you! I can't believe I didn't think of a local storage option. I ended up using session storage and clearing appropriately. Extremely helpful, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to run function postValues() "onClick" of button type=submit and use session variables, following the same logic as in this post: [Auto Increment in Session using Javascript is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27840425/auto-increment-in-session-using-javascript-is-not-working)

I clear the sessionStorage variables in another file.

Working code:

```
function postValues() {

if(sessionStorage.getItem("count") == null){

  counter=sessionStorage.setItem("count", 1);
  counters = 1;

} else {

  counters= parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("count")); 
  counters++;
  counter=sessionStorage.setItem("count", counters);

}

alert(counters);

document.getElementById("counter").value = counter; 

}
```